# data.table alternative for dplyr mutate?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm learning R and I'm not sure if it makes sense to standardise on dplyr or data.table. Dplyr has really nice syntax, but as far as I understand it copies data frame on each operation, which is (or could be) a drawback.

One thing that I can't figure out is alternative for mutate.

if I have

```
df %>% group_by(foo) %>% mutate(
    bar  = cumsum(baz),
    q    = bar * 3.14)
```

I could do sth like

```
df[,c("bar"):=list(cumsum(baz)),by=foo]
df$q <- df$bar*3.14
```

Is there a better way of doing this in data.table?

Comment: reproducible example please ... ?

Comment: For starters, you don't need neither `c` or `list` in your first line. Your second line is somewhat a sudden draw back to base R syntax. Why are you suddenly using `<-` and `$` again? Why not like in your first line do something like `df[,q:=bar*3.14]`?

Comment: Is there a difference between using one or the other syntax (other than personal preference)? I mean, in the first line I need that syntax due to "..., by=foo]".

Comment: You mentioned yourself that you don't want to copy your data. So `<-` and `$` makes a copy. If you use `:=` within the data table scope you are avoiding the copy. That's the whole point of `:=` - it updates *by reference*.

Comment: <- and ? make copies? Wow, that's kinda counterintuitive. Sorry, I don't understand the internals and it's not obvious from the syntax those would make copies.

So the benefit of mutate here is it makes one copy for the whole operation I suppose? On the other hand, I read there was a bug in it and it doesn't use shallow copy when used with data.table.

Comment: Almost any operation in R except for `data.table` functions like `:=`, `setnames`, etc. makes copies.

Answer (score 15):

The idiomatic way of doing this with `data.table` would be:

```
dt[, c("bar", "q") := {
       tmp = cumsum(baz)
       list(tmp, tmp*3.14)
     }, by = foo]
```

`data.table` evaluates the j-expression at the same time, not separately (on purpose), and therefore you can't refer to the updated value unless you store it in a variable.

This avoids surprises in many cases. One useful scenario is:

```
dt[, c("a", "b") := list(pmin(a,b), pmax(a,b))]
```

`:=`'s behaviour is the same as base, just that it updates the input object by reference. It's not equivalent to `mutate`.

Comment: thank you for the additional `pmin` vs `pmax` example, that really helped illustrate the concept.

Comment: @Arun I didnot understand the 'dt[, c("a", "b") := list(pmin(a,b), pmax(a,b))]' example here. What is it suppose to illustrate?

Comment: @deb, that `j` is evaluated altogether. If `a` was evaluated as `pmin(a, b)` first, then `b`  will always be `b` as `pmax(a, b)` will be comparing with the new value of `a`.

Answer (score 14):

You may do just this:

```
# some test data:
df <- data.table(baz = 1:10, foo = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))

df[, bar := cumsum(baz), by = foo]
df[, q := bar*3.14]
```

While being in two lines, it is very readable and easy to write.